# Serialize more complicated structure to JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization

I have a `NSArray` of custom objects (only `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSNumber`) and I need to send this JSON to the server. Using `NSJSONSerialization` throws an error because it is not a property list.

Is there any other way, except manually creating a `NSString` object  in JSON format?

```
NSString *manualPost = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"key1\": \"%@\",\"key2\": \"%@\",\"key3\": %@,\"keyArray4\": [%@]}", val1, val2, val3, valArray4];
```

Comment: use josnfragment and get string of json and then send server.

Comment: Convert the objects to the equivalent NSDictionary objects and serialize the dictionaries.

Comment: `dict = @{"key1":va1, "key2":val2 ... "keyArray4":valArray4};`

Comment: This is much better solution but what if I have just an array of objects? `[{color: "red",value: "#f00"},{color: "green",value: "#0f0"}]`

Comment: Of course, this is very simple example, but what if I have an array of `nsarray`, `nsstring` ...

Comment: Build the structure one layer at a time.  It's not hard, it just requires a bit of thought.  Usually best to work with mutable dictionaries and arrays, and then you can add each item separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question, right answer is using dictionary and values can be `NSArrays`, `NSNumber`s, `NSString`s - in other words - Property List.

Sample:

```
NSDictionary *postDictionary = @{@"key1": @"value1",
                                 @"key2": @(1),
                                 @"key3":@[@"key3", @(5.9)]
                                 };


NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSLog(@"PostData %@", postData);
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```